# What are the differences between SproutCore 1.x and 2.0?

Tags: javascript-framework, sproutcore, sproutcore-2

If you look at the SproutCore framework right now, there are 2 versions to go with: A 1.7 beta and a 2.0 beta. The docs and guides seem to be different as they are served from different domains, but sometimes you just don't know if a tutorial or even the copy texts on sproutcore.com are referring to version 1.x or 2.

It's a bit confusing and so I am asking about the difference(s) of both. Is version 2 even comparable to the previous one? It seems to have a totally different approach.

Would be good to know, so someone could easily decide which version fits best for a certain usecase.

Comment: SproutCore 2.0 is now renamed to Ember.js http://emberjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. SC1 and SC2 are very different.

Here's a good video I found that provides the background and reasoning behind SC2. http://vimeo.com/25210161

The recommendation for the SC team on the [blog](http://blog.sproutcore.com/announcing-sproutcore-2-0/):

> Remember: SproutCore 1.6 is still the best way to write desktop-style
>   apps, and will continue to be maintained and developed by the core
>   team and contributors. Right now, SproutCore 2.0 is the best choice
>   only if you are building web-style apps, or want to augment an
>   existing application.

Here's my own experience with SC1 v SC2: http://blog.chililog.org/2011/10/14/sproutcore-v1-vs-v2/

IMHO, use SC1 if you plan to write a native style ipad or iphone app.  It has views and transitions that you can use "out of the box".

Use SC2 if you plan to write a web style app like the twitter UI.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps very much, thx! So, as you said, SC1 is still suitable for iPhone/iPad web apps? I wonder if the bigger size is somehow a problem when building for mobile. Thats seems to be the chalange: Choosing the big SC1 or the tiny, modular SC2 where you may be missing something...

Comment: With SC1, there's a reference in this blog to dynamic framework loading which may speed up your load times.  http://blog.sproutcore.com/postback-datastore-improvements-and-dynamic-loading/